# The item name "__Standard Values" is already definied on this level

Tags: workflow, permissions

I had to change some permissions around so that some users would be able to modify templates.  All users should have at least read access to all templates.  I just tried to move my item through the workflow but I'm getting this error now.

I've tried moving it through the workflow via a user with admin rights, and they don't get this warning, so I assume it's a permission issue, but the question is, what permission access is causing this, I've never seen this message before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to narrow this down to a read deny permission for the item \Templates\sytem and descendants.  Removing that solved the issue.